# Запуск функции с параметрами через openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Есть у меня оракловский сервер на, котором есть некая функция, используемая примерно так:

```
select xxx, function(xxx) as yyy from oracle table
```

Еще есть MSSQL Server, связанный с оракловским через linked server+odbc, на котором также нужно вызывать именно эту функцию, и непременно с самого оракла, а параметры брать строго локально.

В прямом запросе через openquery отлично работает:

```
select * from openquery(ORACLE,'select function(somedata) from dual')
```

Но мне-то нужно передавать параметр somedata непосредственно из запроса на mssql, так что делаю скалярную функцию-обертку с телом типа:

```
begin
select @result = result from openquery(ORACLE,'select function('+ @somedata +) as result from dual)'
return result
```

и сталкиваюсь с тем, что [openquery does not accept variables for its arguments](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314520).
Пробую через dynamic sql:

```
set @sql=select ...
exec @sql
```

и натыкаюсь на *dynamic sql is not allowed in stored function or trigger*.

Копаю дальше и делаю для функции еще одну обертку-процедуру с output-параметром:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @params nvarchar(max),result numeric;
set @sql=n'select @resultOut = result from openquery(ORACLE,''select function('+@somedata+') as result from dual'');';
set @params=n'@resultOut numeric output';
execute sp_executesql @sql, @params, @resultOut=@result output;
```

вызываю из открытого кода - отлично работает. Вызываю из функции - [You cannot execute a command with exec or sp_executesql nor can execute a stored procedure in a function](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f3030ba5-863b-4363-b7cd-53f6ad965b32/exec-in-sql-functions).

Как мне передать параметры в openquery и вернуть оттуда результат непосредственно из запроса на mssql server?

Comment: Т.е. ваша функция не использует данные таблицы, а получает на вход константу, насколько я понял. Тогда можно попробовать следующее. Создавать временную таблицу в Оракле, вставлять туда строку с нужным значением из SQL server, а затем вызывать функцию, которая будет использовать значение из этой временной таблицы.

Comment: Да, мне необходимо в ходе запроса отправлять локальные (mssql) данные удаленной (oracle) функции и самым элегантным решением мне виделась локальная функция-обертка, обменивающаяся данными с удаленной через openquery. Но вот что-то никак не удается заставить ее работать именно в виде функции. Вариант с удаленной временной таблицей или же с локальной, заполняемой через все-таки работающую хранимую процедуру тоже приходил в голову, но выглядит он уже не так симпатично, хотя, если другого выхода не найдется, то придется так и действовать.

Comment: А локально (в mssql) вы планируете её использовать подобно тому как она используется в oracle? Т.е. `select xxx, function(xxx) as yyy from table`?

Comment: да, только xxx брать локально, а обрабатывать удаленно. это отлично работает с хранимой процедурой, но хранимку в запрос не засунешь.

Comment: ок, постараюсь быть более лаконичным

Comment: Можно написать sqlclr скалярную функцию-обёртку, которая будет делать динамический запрос, но, возможно, действительно будет оптимальнее отправить нужные данные в Oracle (сразу все, а не построчно), там посчитать, а потом забрать посчитанные данные.

Comment: Данные нужно из оракла передать в MSSQL? Если да -  могу кинуть пример на ADO. У меня нужно передавать в MSSQL таблицу из информикса в MSSQL и есть готовый пример.

Answer (score 1):

Подразумевается, что в MSSQL нужно передать данные, зная выборку для другой СУБД. Для этого можно создать в ODBC алиас к другой СУБД, например **odbc_alias** и сделать SQL запрос к удалённой (или локальной) субд.

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[wsp_get_data]  ( @b char(13)  )
RETURNS 

  @tab TABLE  ( ev int,  fio varchar(255))
AS
BEGIN  
/*  sp_configure ‘show advanced options’, 1;  GO RECONFIGURE;
   sp_configure ‘Ole Automation Procedures’, 1; GO RECONFIGURE; + настройка контактной зоны галочка */

declare @ado int; -- Переменные для ADO запроса
declare @db int;
declare @rs int;
declare @fields int;
declare @field int;
declare @hr int;
declare @eof int;
declare @a0  varchar(255) --  Переменные для таблицы
declare @a1 varchar(15)

set @sql =  'select  pid.recipient, pid.fio from tab1 where' + @b

EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Connection', @ado OUT, 1
if @hr=0 exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @ado, 'Open', NULL, 'odbc_alias'
if @hr=0 EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @ado, 'Execute', @rs OUT, @sql

set @eof = 1
if @hr=0 exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @rs, 'EOF', @eof out

declare @t int
set @t = 100

while @eof = 0 and @hr = 0 begin

   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod  @rs , 'fields', @fields out
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod  @fields  , 'item',  @field out, 0; 
   EXEC @hr =   sp_OAMethod  @field  , 'value',   @a0 out; 
   exec sp_OADestroy @field
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod  @fields  , 'item',  @field out, 1; 
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod  @field  , 'value',   @a1 out; 
   exec sp_OADestroy @field
   exec sp_OADestroy @fields
   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod  @rs, 'MoveNext'
   insert into @tab values(@a0,@a1);
   set @eof = -1
   if @hr = 0 exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @rs, 'EOF', @eof out
   end

if @rs is not null  exec sp_OADestroy @rs
if @db is not null  exec sp_OADestroy @db
if @ado is not null exec sp_OADestroy @ado  
RETURN 
END
```