# Как получить данные SqlServer на C?

Tags: sql, c, sql-server

Необходимо получить данные с БД на си. С помощью чего это лучше сделать?

Comment: Много зависит от того какая БД используется.

Comment: @Alex.B Sql Server

Comment: @nick_n_a да я всё мучаюсь с одним и тем же, вот и спрашиваю. Спасибо

Comment: Возможно есть самописные решения, которые попроще...

Comment: @nick_n_a я смотрел всё это, понял, что намного проще в свой С код будет передавать данные из c++. а там уже всё делать основное

Comment: Вы в ответе ожидаете увидеть что? Просто код с одним select для разных библиотек?

Comment: @nick_n_a я лишь ожидал увидеть направление. Потому что по C я гуглю разные пути, как получить данные из Sql Server и мало что нахожу. Говорят про ODBC, но примеров хороших не нашел, вот и прихожу сюда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько извесных библиотек-интерфейсов, через которые с базой можно работать или напрямую или почти напрямую. В С, С++ доступны

1. ODBC
2. ADO
3. OleDB

MSSQL - относится к OleDB базе.

Покажу некоторые. ODBC и ADO. ODBC и ADO - очень похожи. Можно в коннекте писать как алиас, который в панеле управления можно зарегистрировать в "OdbcCad", так и строку подключения. Строка подключения отличается от строки подключения OleDB.

ODBC - это около сотни (нужных порядка 20-30) функций, с помощью которых можно получить доступ к базе.
Ниже минимальный пример использования ODBC, без обработки ошибок:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
// #pragma comment (lib,"odbc32.lib")   Для борланда

int main(int argc, const char ** argv) {
  HANDLE hEnv=0;
  HANDLE hodbc=0;
  HANDLE stmt =0;
  int err = 0;
  int a = 0;
  int nula;
  err=SQLAllocEnv(&hEnv);
  SQLAllocConnect(hEnv,&hodbc);
  SQLConnect(hodbc,"mytest",-3/*SQL_NTS*/,"portal",-3,"1",-3); 
  SQLAllocStmt(hodbc,&stmt);
  SQLPrepare(stmt,"select 123 as a",-3);
  err = SQLExecute(stmt);
  if ((SQLFetch(stmt) | 1) == 1) {
     SQLGetData(stmt,1,SQL_C_LONG,&a,1,&nula);
     printf("%i",a);
     };
if (stmt != SQL_NULL_HSTMT) SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, stmt);
if (hodbc!= SQL_NULL_HDBC) {
    SQLDisconnect(hodbc);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hodbc);
}
if (hEnv != SQL_NULL_HENV) SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
return 0;
};
```

Ссылки ODBC

1. http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/examples/DescribeAndBindColumns.html
2. http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetdata-function

---

Вариант с АDO. Мне кажется, что это самый простой вариант - и подходит для большинства СУБД. АDO - предполагает юникод, подключение по строке подключения или алиасу. Самым простым я его считаю, благодаря тому что он представляет собой порядка 10 классов, в которые собраны все функции которые нужны для работы с СУБД. VARIANT - тип облегчает преобразования, не обязательно преобразовывать. Все функции возвращают HRESULT - код ошибки можно а)нагуглить б)есть функции, преобразующие его в текст. COM-совместимый интерфейс позволяет использовать дополнительные ф-ции облегчающие преобразование. Так же ADO хорошо работает в скриптах JS, VBS, и в самом MS-SQL SQL-скрипте (при включемом Active-X).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <adoint.h>    
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char ** argv) {
  CoInitialize(0); // Нужно делать в начале программы
  GUID g1;
  CLSIDFromProgID(L"ADODB.Connection", &g1); // Система сама посдставит последнюю версию
  Connection15 * conn = NULL; // 15 не означает что АДО устарела, для совместимости
  ADORecordset * rs = NULL;
  DWORD res = 0;
  VARIANT_BOOL eof = VARIANT_TRUE;
  if ((res =  CoCreateInstance(*(GUID*)&g1, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
   IID_IUnknown, (void**)&conn))) return res; // Подключаем либу АДО
  if ((res = conn->Open(L"mytest",L"portal",L"1",0))  != 0) return res;
  // В execute нужно поставить SQL запрос
  res = conn->Execute(L"select 123 a;",0,0,&rs); 
  if (res == 0) {
    rs->MoveFirst();
    if ((rs->get_EOF(&eof) == 0) && (eof== 0))  { // Тут 
        //можно будет поставить while вместо if
        VARIANT index= {0,};
        VARIANT val = {0,};
        index.vt = VT_I4;
        index.intVal = 0; // номер колонки
        long ct = 0;
        ADOFields* pFields = NULL;
        ADOField*  pField = NULL;
        res= rs->get_Fields(&pFields);
        if (res==0) pFields->get_Count(&ct);// Получить число столбцов
        for (index.intVal=0; index.intVal < ct; index.intVal++){              
          if (res==0) res=pFields->get_Item(index,&pField);// Колонка 0
          if  (res == 0) res = pField->get_Value(&val);
          if ((res == 0) &&(val.vt != VT_BSTR))
            VariantChangeType(&val,&val,0,VT_BSTR);  // Конвертация грубо в строку
          if ((res==0)&&(val.vt == VT_BSTR)) {// Вывод на екран
             printf("%ls",val.bstrVal);
             };
          VariantClear(&val); // Освобождаем ресурсы
          if (pField) pField->Release();
          }
        if (pFields) pFields->Release();
        rs->MoveNext(); // Надо если в цикле
        }
    }
  return 0;

}
```

Ссылки АDO

1. http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=689078
2. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/ado-code-examples-in-visual-c
3. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526743/17974) АDO + SQL

---

3. Пример на OLEDB приводить не буду. Трудно написать кратко что нужно. Хотя для MSSQL OLEDB - лучше всего подходит. Приведу несколько ссылок с примерами.

   1. Описание шагов OLEDB https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746473(v=vs.85).aspx
   2. MS пример LDAP https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705932(v=vs.85).aspx
   3. Обширный пример https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716835(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ничего себе, вы расписали. Спасибо большое. Обязательно использую это в своей программе. Иначе бы переносил из С++ данные в Си.
Просто на более низком языке намного сложнее прописывать такое и с моими знаниями порой это слишком сложно. Поэтому и приходится тут слишком *для чайника* спрашивать

Comment: Мне мой ответ не нравится тем, что я никогда не реализовывал запросы с параметрами. Возможно со временем дополню параметрами, или почитав этот ответ кто-то дополнит лучшим. По отдельности каждая особенность в интернене есть. Приходится собирать "всё до кучи". MSSQL не любит "константные" параметры которые варьируются в широком диапазоне. Если программа сложная - прийдётся их освоить самостоятельно, или дополнительно искать примеры.

Comment: Информации в интернете много, но последнее время сложно найти хорошие реализации.