# C++ и Active Directory: ADDS vs ADSI

Tags: c++, active-directory

Есть два инструмента взаимодействия с AD -  это *Active Directory Domain Services* и *Active Directory Service Interfaces*. Если я правильно понял, то первое - это просто сервис с поддержкой ldap (+ куча фич для AD), а второе - это com-интерфейсы.

**Вопрос:** что лучше и проще использовать для плюсов. Глаза разбегаются, а время идет. Вроде работа с com очень проста, но сервис предоставляет больше детальных возможностей.

Не обязательно C++, если на другом языке есть хорошая библиотека, то можете посоветовать.

Comment: Есть вариант, через то же ADO работать с LDAP как с СУБД.

Comment: @nick_n_a, C++/CLI? Тогда вопрос, Я тут хорошо погуглил и нашел на python 2 библиотеки LDAP. Так вот, через это протокол я могу управлять всеми объектами AD?

Comment: в C# есть все, что необходимо для работы с AD. Если C# подходит, конечно.

Comment: ADO - хороша тем, что на с++ есть интерфейс ADO конкретно для с++ (не CLI). Для с# ADO не используют обычно, поскольку его заменяет достаточно хороший OdbcConnection и OleDbConnection. Но всётаки в с# есть и свои либы для AD (MrBin прав). Конкретно ADO - это упрощение. Не могу сказать полный функционал оно предоставляет или частично много не хватает. Но как плюс - переносимость на другие языки. По крайней мере sql-кодов.

Comment: Пример ADO + LDAP (без с++) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746471(v=vs.85).aspx, пример ADO для с++ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803165/17974

Comment: Если у вас задача очень небольшая, то я советую js+ADO+LDAP или vbs+ADO+LDAP. Рабочие примеры найти не трудно в сети.

Comment: @nick_n_a на небольшую задачу и повершел хорошо заходит :]

Comment: @nick_n_a, Т.е. ADO - это порт с c#? Или все-таки это C++/CLI. ADO ведь из .Net мира вроде. А про задачу точно сказать не могу. Больше 1 домена в ближайшее время (год, может 2) не будет. Мне нужно всего-лишь создавать/удалять/изменять группы/организации/пользователи и редактировать политики (Для этого Ad и предназначена). Можете оформить ваш комментарий как ответ.